# Simulated keystrokes does not always work

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard

I have a application that on a user request sends some keyboard commands to another program. In order to do that, I use http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

The problem is that every now and then, the keyboard presses are not received to the destination application.

I have written a test program that simulates this, see below.
Some runs, it works perfectly and some runs it fail regularly. What caused this? How can I prevent it?
One way of course is to add a delay before keyboard presses, but the question is how long delay is reasonable. Ideally, I'd like to avoid a delay.

```
private void SendKeyTest(IntPtr mainWindow, IntPtr receiverWindow)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (!_cancle)
    {
        // Set receiver application as active
        NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(receiverWindow);

        // Send the keyboard presses
        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(string.Format("{0,5:N0}\n", index++));

        // Return to the main application
        NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(mainWindow);

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're switching foreground windows back and forth from 'yours' to 'theirs'? Or does the swapping only occur in the test program?

Comment: Use a real automation interface, or AutoHotKey. Seems unlikely that you will be able to switch foreground window like that. You can give it away, but you can't take it back.

Comment: You may also need to add a delay *after* you send the keypresses. Sending input is asynchronous; the keyboard events get added to the input queue, but not necessarily processed immediately; so it's possible that if you switch input immediately after, some of the input ends up going there instead. Typical approach with testing is to wait until you see the results of the input before proceeding to the next stage; "fire and forget" doesn't usually work too well.